# UITextField vs. UIPickerView in UITableViewCell?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uipickerview, uitextfielddelegate

What is the most suitable way to handle the product quantity for a catalog ordering iPad app. I am currently struggling trying to set up this values with `UITextField`s in `UITableViewCell`s. The app displays the products in an alphabetical way depending on the first letter for the product. I have it set up using a `SegmentedControl` inside a `UINavigationBar` which refreshes the cells depending on the alphabet letter tapped, displaying only the products for that letter which is not the same across the board.

I posted a [question yesterday to set up UITextFields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146747/how-to-pull-the-text-value-for-a-uitextfield-inside-a-uitableviewcell) for which using the `UITextFieldDelegate` was the answer I was more inclined to use. The problem that I still face with that option is that when I enter a number for the `textField`, it for some reason displays it on other cells. When I scroll up and down the list it keeps populating random cells with that value, and in some cases, removing the value from the cell that should actually have it.

Today, I am growing desperate and am trying to find options to handle those quantities. Probably using a `UIPickerView`, or some other type. Has anyone worked on something like an ordering catalog? Any shared info on how to approach this is more than greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work perfectly using a mutable dictionary to store the values using the shouldReturn method for the UITextFieldDelegate. From there, I would simply make it display the matching value from the dictionary to the productCode.

Answer (score 0):

My first inclination is that you should implement `-tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` and use the index path to determine the current quantity associated with that item. Not sure how your data is setup, but I would keep this information in an associated array.

Here's an example

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger *quantity = [quantities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", quantity];
}
```